# How do I get the times of alarms set in Google's DeskClock app?

Tags: android, clock, alarm

Root access is possible.
Basically I need a way to read content:`//settings/system/alarm_alert` from an application and get the time (or time remaining) of the alarms.

I found the old project android-alarm-database, but that only works for the older alarm clock application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The DeskClock application (that replaced the older AlarmClock application) sets alarms using the Alarm Manager. Unfortunately its not possible to read the existing alarms from the Alarm Manager, unless you know the PendingIntent that created it. DeskClock stores these PendingIntents, as well as other alarm information, in an internal database. However, there is another way to discover the time of the last alarm set or removed:

DeskClock sends out a broadcast intent called `android.intent.action.ALARM_CHANGED` when it updates the status bar icon (with an extra boolean `alarmSet` to indicate on/off) and updates `Systems.Settings.NEXT_ALARM_FORMATTED` which you can receive using the following broadcast receiver:

```
private static final String tag = "TestReceiver"; 
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    Log.d(tag, "intent=" + intent);
    Boolean message = intent.getBooleanExtra("alarmSet",false);
    Log.d(tag, "alarmSet: " + message);
    Log.d(tag, "next alarm: " + Settings.System.getString(context.getContentResolver(),android.provider.Settings.System.NEXT_ALARM_FORMATTED));    
}
```

and with the following intent filter in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<receiver android:name=".TestReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ALARM_CHANGED"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Do you know how to change this to milliseconds? Settings.System.getString(context.getContentResolver(),android.provider.Settings.System.NEXT_ALARM_FORMATTED)

Comment: DeskClock does not allow you to set the time in milliseconds, so reading the time in milliseconds is not useful. If you're working in milliseconds, Calendar.getTimeInMillis() or System.currentTimeMillis() may be more useful to look at, depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Note - no longer works in Lollipop. Intent was private, and now they've removed access to it.

Comment: Use this instead for lollipop - and also the mentioned getNextAlarmClock(): https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#ACTION_NEXT_ALARM_CLOCK_CHANGED